# How to get difference between dates in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, datediff

I have seen other answers but my question is different because I want to get the difference between two dates and use it in the `where` clause but its asking me to enter days to get difference. The dates are coming from my database.

```
Select datediff(D, cid, ced) as theDateDiff
from customers 

Select datediff(D, cid, ced) as theDateDiff
from customers where theDateDiff>=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `cid` and `ced` are fields in your `customers` table, you may wish to try the following:

```
select * from customers c where datediff("d", c.cid, c.ced) >= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider following two issues involving your MS Access SQL:

1. In most cases with some exceptions, you cannot use an alias of a calculated column in other parts of same level query. You can however use such an alias if residing in another query or subquery.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT *, DateDiff("d", cid, ced) AS theDateDiff
         FROM customers) sub  
   where theDateDiff >= 5
   ```
2. The [DateDiff](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/datediff-function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f) function in MS Access differs from the [DateDiff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of SQL Server where the latter appears to be the version you use with unquoted `D` as first argument. Remember no two dialects in the relational database world are exactly alike even if under same parent company.

   Therefore, replace `DateDiff(D, cid, ced)` with `DateDiff("d", cid, ced)`.

   To cite another example other than Microsoft, Oracle (company) now manages MySQL which is a very different RDBMS with much different dialect than flagship database: Oracle.